# Browsers not showing any font on 22.04 ARM64

Tags: firefox, fonts, 22.04, chromium, arm

I have an M1 Macbook Pro, and used [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/) to install a 22.04 ubuntu on a VM, using the ARM64 version as mentioned [here](https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/ubuntu-20-04),

Firefox is not opening at all,

Chrome is not getting installed, because they didn't release an ARM64 version,

and even Chromium, is showing up with no text at all

What should I do to fix Chromium?

[image]

---

### Edit

I tried 20.04 and it doesn't have this problem

Answer (score 1):

I made Firefox functional by disabling wayland.

Comment: Would you please mention how to disable wayland?

Comment: you can disable by https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux